# Graduated symbol for percentage attribute in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I want to use the Graduated Symbol style for a field which contains values in percentages. When I select the Graduated Symbol this field does not appear in the drop down box. Is there a way to make this field appear?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the field that does not appear in drop down box is String Type. Try to create new field of Integer or Real Type and calculate new values by Field Calculator.

Comment: Thank you! What I did was to delete the % sign in excel and re-import it in QGIS. However now I need to find out a way of displaying the % sign. Thanks.

Comment: `concat("percentage attribute",'%')`